# React router v6 routes with Fallback

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to implement routes with fallback in the react router v6.
I got this error:

Uncaught Error: [RouteWithFallbackBoundary] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

```
const RouteWithFallbackBoundary = (props: PathRouteProps) => (
    <Route {...props}>
        <MyErrorBoundary key={props.path}>
            <Suspense fallback={"loading"}>{props.children}</Suspense>
        </MyErrorBoundary >
    </Route>
);
```

```
const MY_ROUTES = {
    test: {
        path: '/test',
        component: lazy(() => import('../Component/Test')),
    }
}
```

```
  <Routes>
            <RouteWithFallbackBoundary path={MY_ROUTES.test.path}>
                <MY_ROUTES.test.component />
            </RouteWithFallbackBoundary>
  </Routes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to invert the `Route` and the `RouteWithFallbackBoundary` components so the `Route` is what is rendered into the `Routes` component.

Example:

```
const RouteWithFallbackBoundary = ({ children }) => (
  <MyErrorBoundary>
    <Suspense fallback={"loading"}>
      {children}
    </Suspense>
  </MyErrorBoundary >
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path={MY_ROUTES.test.path}
    element={(
      <RouteWithFallbackBoundary>
        <MY_ROUTES.test.component />
      </RouteWithFallbackBoundary>
    )}
  />
</Routes>
```